# Update dataframe column by group according to match with another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
ID    Date           Value
A     2017-01-01     3
B     2017-01-01     3
C     2017-01-01     3
C     2017-01-02     3
C     2017-01-03     3
D     2017-01-01     3

df2
ID    Date           Ratio
C     2017-01-01     3
```

And I want to update values in df1 from a corresponding entry in df2 such that Value = Value * Ratio if the following two conditions are met:

1. The ID in df1 matches with an ID in df2
2. The Date in df1 is after the Date in df2

Here is my desired output:

```
df1
ID    Date           Value
A     2017-01-01     3
B     2017-01-01     3
C     2017-01-01     3
C     2017-01-02     9
C     2017-01-03     9
D     2017-01-01     3
```

Any help please? I'm thinking of using aggregate and match but not sure how to piece them together.

Comment: Hi @Anna you received a couple of good answers. Please consider accepting the solution that worked for you. This lets the community know the answer worked and that the issue is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `data.table` non-equi join; Use `:=` to update *Value* column for matched rows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2);

df1[df2, on = .(ID = ID, Date > Date), Value := Value * Ratio]

df1
#   ID       Date Value
#1:  A 2017-01-01     3
#2:  B 2017-01-01     3
#3:  C 2017-01-01     3
#4:  C 2017-01-02     9
#5:  C 2017-01-03     9
#6:  D 2017-01-01     3
```

---

Here is a syntax sugar for `ID = ID` thanks to @Frank:

```
df1[df2, on = .(ID, Date > Date), Value := Value * Ratio]
```

Comment: @Frank Exactly.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom and @Frank! I'm actually getting the error "unused argument (on = .(ID = ID, Date > Date))"- any clue what this means?

Comment: What data.table version are you using? You probably need to upgrade your data.table package. Non-equi join is introduced in version 1.10.0+ if I remember correctly.

Comment: Alternately, you may have missed the `setDT` step, @Anna , since `on=` has been a valid argument since the Sept 2015 CRAN release of the package.

Answer (score 2):

Merge df1 and df2 by `ID`, change `Value` only if condition is met, unselect side-effect columns, rename columns to original names

```
library(dplyr)
desired <- left_join(df1, df2, by="ID") %>%
             mutate(Value=ifelse(is.na(Date.x > Date.y), Value, Value*Ratio)) %>%
             select( -Date.y, Ratio ) %>%
             setNames( c("ID","Date","Value") )
```

Comment: Thanks @Chi Pak! This is  great except for one detail- I noticed the parameter is Date.x > Date.y (aka strictly greater than); however, my output shows a mutated Value for all entries corresponding to ID C. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: Just a guess...are your `Dates` `as.Dates` or `characters`?

Comment: I cast them as dates using `df2<-data.frame(c("C"), c(as.Date("2017-01-01")), c(3))` but when I checked `typeof(df2$Date)` I got double...I'm guessing this could be why?

Comment: Yes, most likely, the conversion from Date to numeric is quixotic